# storebox doesn't work before begin{document} like normal savebox

Tags: boxes

One can use [`storebox`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/storebox/storebox.pdf) package to save space.

For example, I will expect that this works as it is similar to the use of `savebox`. However, it does not. One needs to move the `\storebox{\foobox}{FOO}` inside the `\begin{document}` to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{storebox}
\newstorebox{\foobox}

% moving this line inside begin{document} works
\storebox{\foobox}{FOO}

\begin{document}
 \usestorebox{\foobox}
\end{document}
```

Now, consider this

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\savebox{\foobox}{FOO}
\begin{document}
 \usebox{\foobox}
\end{document}
```

This option with `savebox` works.

So, how can I make the use of `\storebox` before `\begin{document}` work as `savebox`?

Comment: Neither `\savebox` nor `\storebox` should be used before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: If I need to initialize something in the boxes, and use them inside the document, what would be the proper way of do it? For example, I may need to initialize something within a style or package, and use it through a macro in the main document. What would be the correct way then?

Answer (score 3):

The document font setup is expected to be completed when `\begin{document}` is processed, which includes a `\normalfont` declaration to finish up all font requests.

Doing `\savebox` in the preamble provides *no* guarantee that the fonts will match those of the document: several font packages delay their actions with `\AtBeginDocument`, so they can take advantage of knowing all loaded packages. The same applies to `\storebox`.

If you want to have `\savebox` or `\storebox` in the preamble or in a package, try with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{storebox}

\newstorebox{\foobox}

\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \storebox{\foobox}{whatever}%
}
```

or just do `\storebox{\foobox}{whatever}` after `\begin{document}` if it's just document code. Note that code delayed with `\AfterEndPreamble` is executed after any code delayed with `\AtBeginDocument`. You can have as many `\AfterEndPreamble` commands as you want, their effect is cumulative.