# Package animate conflicts with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, animate

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{animate}

\providecommand{\actiontext}{Attention}
\newtcolorbox{achtungbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  colframe=white,
  natural height,
  colback=black!10,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
  boxrule=0.3mm,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,left=2mm,width=\linewidth,
  leftrule=13mm,
  title={\small{\actiontext}},
  attach title to upper={\par\smallskip},
  underlay={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=6mm,yshift=-6mm]frame.north west) {\ifpdf\includegraphics[width=10mm]{warning}\fi};
  },
  #1
}

\providecommand{\achtung}[1]{
\begin{achtungbox}
#1
\end{achtungbox}
}

\begin{document}

\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}
\achtung{AAA}
% \newpage
\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}

\achtung{I would expect the same figure in both animates at the start, but it does not. Sure, this is not the real case, but timeline options enables me to start animatens from different frames, this is currently impossible, seems to me. timeline option is not used here..., wanted to show a special animation at the intro of lectorenotes and later at the chapter.}

\end{document}
```

Seems to me that I am able to hunt bugs very successfully...

I would expect to see identical figures before starting animation.

Download `warning.pdf` and `pdstestg-pics.pdf` at
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5y5rgralnw1pj8h/AABxTyDrCDUqo80ZtRF_rVTba?dl=0

Comment: The culprit is the `underlay` in the `achtungbox`, but I can't say why this is causing problems

Comment: That's clearly a bug of the `animate` package (though it is unrelated to `tcolorbox`). I'll have a look into it.

Comment: A bug fix is on the way to CTAN (`animate` v. `[2016/02/15]`)

Comment: Seems, that one problem is solved. (figure is seen as the workaround) but only the second animation can be played, the first wont be played clicking on the play button. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: No, both play nicely on my end.

Comment: Ok it seems a Reader issue, which has been fixed hopefully. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295715 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion of the graphic file seems to upset `animate` -- however, if the graphic file is put into a box, the whole compilation runs and the desired feature is shown.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{animate}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[width=10mm]{warning}}

\providecommand{\actiontext}{Attention}
\newtcolorbox{achtungbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  colframe=white,
  natural height,
  colback=black!10,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
  boxrule=0.3mm,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,left=2mm,width=\linewidth,
  leftrule=13mm,
  title={\small{\actiontext}},
  attach title to upper={\par\smallskip},
  underlay={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=6mm,yshift=-6mm]frame.north west) {%
      \ifpdf
      \usebox{\mybox}%
      \fi
  };
  },
  #1
}

\providecommand{\achtung}[1]{
\begin{achtungbox}
#1
\end{achtungbox}
}

\begin{document}

\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}

\achtung{AAA}
% \newpage
\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}

\achtung{I would expect the same figure in both animates at the start, but it does not. Sure, this is not the real case, but timeline options enables me to start animatens from different frames, this is currently impossible, seems to me. timeline option is not used here..., wanted to show a special animation at the intro of lectorenotes and later at the chapter.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were minutes faster than me. I also found that the `\includegraphics` caused the problem, but you also found a way to circumvent the problem :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Yes, I found a way to circumvent, but not the cause. I assume it's the boxing features of `tcolorbox`, but I leave this to the experts -- do you know one, by chance? ;-)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with `tcolorbox`. The same problem arises, if all `tcolorbox`es are removed and you place a naked `\includegraphics[width=10mm]{warning}` between the animations.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Ah -- I did not remove the `tcolorbox`es so far. Well, it's a feature (as David Carlisle would say, others call it a bug ;-)) of `animate` then?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm not familiar with the `animate` package, but, maybe, it's a known problem with a known solution?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I've not used the package so far at all

Comment: Maybe the author of animate will send some more information, he is informed from me by mail. problem solved.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: Good to know. Thanks! That's why TeX.SE is so nice -- we all work together to find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution above I have improved this one to be used including storebox.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{animate}

% \usepackage{storebox}
% \AtBeginDocument{{}} % see [2]

\providecommand{\newstorebox}[1]{\newsavebox{#1}} % <- fallback is no storebox is used
\providecommand{\storebox}[1]{\savebox{#1}}  % <- fallback is no storebox is used
\providecommand{\usestorebox}[1]{\usebox{#1}}  % <- fallback is no storebox is used

\newstorebox{\myboxgnA}     

\AfterEndPreamble{%
    \storebox{\myboxgnA}{\includegraphics[width=10mm]{warning}} 
} % see [1]


\providecommand{\actiontext}{Attention}
\newtcolorbox{achtungbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  colframe=white,
  natural height,
  colback=black!10,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
  boxrule=0.3mm,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,left=2mm,width=\linewidth,
  leftrule=13mm,
  title={\small{\actiontext}},
  attach title to upper={\par\smallskip},
  underlay={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=6mm,yshift=-6mm]frame.north west) {\ifpdf\usestorebox{\myboxgnA}\fi};
  },
  #1
}

\providecommand{\achtung}[1]{
\begin{achtungbox}
#1
\end{achtungbox}
}

\begin{document}

\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}
\achtung{AAA}
% \newpage
\animategraphics[trim=4.75cm 17cm 3.5cm 4.0cm, poster=last,autoplay=false,autoresume=true,autopause=true,loop=false,controls=true,scale=0.75]{8}{pdstestg-pics}{}{}

\achtung{I would expect the same figure in both animates at the start, but it does not. Sure, this is not the real case, but timeline options enables me to start animatens from different frames, this is currently impossible, seems to me. timeline option is not used here..., wanted to show a special animation at the intro of lectorenotes and later at the chapter.}

\end{document}
```

Now may use storebox now, but you don't have to.

references are:

[1] [storebox doesn't work before begin{document} like normal savebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246917/storebox-doesnt-work-before-begindocument-like-normal-savebox) (thanks to egreg)

[2] [Problems combining tikz and storebox: Missing number, treated as zero. With animate, page shipped out with text `graphicx`,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141520/problems-combining-tikz-and-storebox-missing-number-treated-as-zero-with-anim) (thanks to egreg)

Without egreg it would not be possible to provide this solution to the TeX.SE.

Comment: I don't see the point of the wrappers at all....

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but storebox saves the content only once?

Comment: Yes,but why the wrappers? If you don't need the box more than once you don't need this extra setup,in  my point of view

Comment: I have tested once more. You are absolutley right. You cannot understand this, because you are thinking the right way. Thanks for your advice. Should I delete this example?

Comment: No. Just keep it as a more 'general' way instead of using a direct box name