# animate does not animate files in beamer although compilation works

Tags: beamer, animate

I want to add an animation (slideshow over ~70 files) to my beamer presentation. The compilation with `pdflatex` works fine, but the resulting pdf only shows the first image of the animation (or whatever is specified as `poster`).

Providing a MWE will not work well here, but I used something like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Dynamik}
    \centering
    \animategraphics[
        autoplay,
        loop,
        poster=last,
        height=.7\textheight
    ]{1}{./graphics/animation/anim}{1}{10}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I used Adobe Acrobat Reader DC to view the files, and I was able to the the working animations in the `animate` pdf. I am using `Miktex` with `pdflatex`, all packages have been updated to the latest version.

A short comment-driven discussion and a much appreciated compilation help of @Ondrian revealed, that the latex code works fine. The problem has to be somewhere in the compilation chain. 
I tried both with `pdf`s and `png`s, so the file type of the to-be-animated images does not seem to be relevant.
I already updated all relevant packages and refreshed the `Miktex` file name database and the format files. I really don't know where to start with this. Any help?

**Edit:** You can download test files for the animation here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0wu1kvvnsguflz0/AACvlCLGPWwFjJSjZbT79uMka?dl=0

Comment: Can you upload somewhere the pdf file you are including?

Comment: Only if I have to, it is unpublished research work... What could be the problem with the files? Any clues I could get from the logfile or something similar?

Comment: When I compile your code with my pdf, I see no problems, the animations works perfectly. (also MikTex, pdflatex, Acrobat Reader DC)

Comment: @Ondrian See updated question, I added a dropbox link

Comment: This compiles just fine for me, even with your files. I'm afraid the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @Ondrian I was afraid of this... Where to start?

Comment: Not a clue, really. Try to view [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj1f0jzp2swf2qx/document.pdf?dl=0) at your computer. This is the file compiled by me. At least, you can see whether the problem is in your pdf viewer or within the compilation process.

Comment: it works perfectly fine. The problem seems to be somewhere in the compile chain, without leaving extended traces in the log file...

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help with that, not such an expert, sorry. Please, update your question with the current status so that future readers don't have to go through these comments.

Comment: I just tried with your example and the images you provided in the dropbox link and it works fine with TeXLive 2015. After opening with Acrobat Reader nothing happened at first, but after approx a minute the animation started. Maybe it is just a matter of waiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different AR versions seem to behave differently with regard to PageOpen/PageVisible events which are used to initialise the animation. Some fire the latter, others the former when a page is navigated to in AR.

Un update `[2016/02/28]` which evaluates both events, such that none of them is missed, is on the way to CTAN.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the problem came form the last version of Acrobat Reader, Acrobat Reader DC. Something is going wrong with javascrit. If you modified  you code with:

```
\animategraphics[
    controls,
    loop,
    poster=last,
    height=.7\textheight
]{1}{./graphics/animation/anim}{1}{10}
```

and you turn on the java console in Acrobat Reader DC preference you will see the message :

ReferenceError: a0 is not defined
1:Field:Mouse Up

I'am using TexLive 2015 on Mac Os 10.9, and the same problem can be reproduced on a windows configuration.

If you test this modification using previous version of acrobat reader, it works fine, without any error.

So for the moment I'am using the previous version of Acrobat Reader to view PDF with animations.

Best Regards.